# Can you embed a google map into an app with get voice directions?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

Simple question, and I think i may already know that the answer is that I cannot do what I want but i can't find confirmation of it. I want a google map in **voice guided** turn by turn directions mode inside of an activity within my app. **It seems like that can be done through their API, but I can't confirm or find whether that can include the voice guided feature** and without that, it's not very valuable and I might as well launch the installed google maps app itself and have it skip the default activity and go right into the turn by turn mode with voice rather than embedding it in my activity. I have already done that but would rather have it inside of an activity in my app. **Does anybody know for sure if voice guided is offered other than through the installed maps app**? Also, any creative ideas or workarounds would be gladly appreciated as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

It's not directly supported by the Google Maps API.  You could theoretically cobble it together yourself, using the Directions API and TTS, but the main reason you can't do this is legal rather than technical.  From the [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms):

> 10.4.c.iii No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; ...

Comment: pretty much what I suspected. I'm guessing they consider that too valuable and a proprietary feature to let developers use it with their stuff. I'll accept your answer in a little bit. Just want to make sure someone won't disagree. Thanks.

Comment: also, I can't even find anything about voice guided in the directions API, so even if it were legal, it does not appear as though voice guided is even published in their API

Comment: @Bobh You'd have to strip all the HTML out of the Directions API responses and feed it through TTS yourself, using GPS to know when to do it, taking into account the vehicle's speed and the need for the utterance to be completed with enough time for the driver to react to an upcoming maneuver.  It would be pretty complicated.  Lots of work to risk Google yanking your app off the Play Store.